# Capturing or logging subjobs messages in Talend

Tags: talend

I have working in logging part in talend. I have followed this https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=33 and successfully able to log error as well as stats of job (i.e begin end time of job) but I want to capture this information as well as in my logs [image]

the information/message of subjobs like of `csv file` `3 rows in 0.01s 375 rows/s` how to record or capture this information

Answer (score 0):

See `Stats & Logs` in job properties. There you can store this information into files or into a database.

Keep in mind you might need to activate `Monitor this connection` in the row settings.

In the premium model there is also a `Advanced Monitoring Console` available which can be used to visualize those logs out of a database.